# TLS Handshake Error while calling Google Vision API

Tags: python, dns, google-cloud-vision

We are trying to deploy a codebase in corporate/enterprise network. This code was working fine in open internet network but not in corporate/enterprise network

We get the following error
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses

We use Python v3.8

Note: The API call from a rest client such as Postman is successful from the same corporate/enterprise network

Tried enabling debug, it throws an error

Are we missing something, i dont see any port issue as the same url and port is accessible from REST Client/postman app successfully and getting correct response.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from google.cloud import vision
import os

os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://internalproxyserver.com:8080"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://internalproxyserver.com:8080"
# os.environ['GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER'] = 'native'
# os.environ["GRPC_TRACE"] = "api,client_channel_routing,cares_resolver,transport_security,tsi"
# os.environ["GRPC_VERBOSITY"] = "debug"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r"C:\abc.json"
content = b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAZCAYAAADHXotLAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAENElEQVRo3u1ay0u6Sxh+PjWzLI0vxRZWdCEqughGCbWxVu2jG7WIdm3CRYuoP6CoKLpA0CYIg6hNQRTYoqhlBQVBFF1Nu2lmRqBl71n9Bj1mxzodz89zvgcGZuad533Hefzme2eUIyKCgN8GImEJBEEECIIIgggQBBEEYRgcHATHcSFlZGSEjdHpdB+OcTgcYfkfFYPB8GlMjuMgl8tRXFyMnp4ePD4+hp231+vF0NAQysvLoVQqIZfLUVRUhN7eXrhcrn9HEfoBDA8PE4CQMjY2xsbo9foQu0gkIqfTSWazmXie/9DHn0tFRQURUcScrKwsstlsIXO22WxUWFgYlqfRaGh3d5eiDfyUo9PTU0pKSiIAxPM8nZ2dBdl9Ph9NTk6yD9zU1ERutztojFKpZPzNzc2g0tbWFiTIZ5z5+XkyGAwsVmNjYxDH6/VSSUkJs7e0tNDS0hKtrq6SyWQiiURCAEilUpHdbo9NQQIXR6PRfGhfWVlhi9DZ2fkl/vj4OMnlcjIajRFxHh4eSKFQEABKSEig19dXZuvr62Pz6OrqCok1PT0d9MURBAnD/2rMwKfk7u6O9aenpxMAkslk5HA4Qnjv7++Um5tLAEgsFtP19XXUBPnPZllEhJubGwBAQkICeJ4HABwfH8NqtQIAqqurkZqaGsLlOA4NDQ0AAL/fj42NjajNW/JPOPX5fFhfXw/p39/fj4h/e3sLjuOC+mpqarC2thYR/+7uDoODgzg/PwcAtLe3QywWAwBOTk7YuIyMjLA+MjMzWT2QE5OCuFwuGI3GqD4RH4kIAC0tLRgaGmJtj8fD6iqVKqw/tVrN6k9PT7EtyN8Fz/NYXFwM6ktJSfmyH7FYDI7j8PLyAqlUCgBITk5mdofDEZZ7f3/P6gqFIrYF0Wg0bP8OxOrqKmpra/+SHxcXh6qqqm+L+Pz8jJmZGczOzmJmZgZOpxPLy8sAgJycHMa5uLgI6y/Qlp2dHVsHw98xy/L7/ZSfn/9hlqXVagkAxcfHh82y8vLyhCzrM0xNTUEmk6GysjKyOyGRCKWlpaxts9lYvaOjg12d9Pf3h3BnZ2dxdHQEAKirq0NaWtr/+x3y+vqKra2toL6dnR14vV54vd6I/QS+L+x2O3Q6HQDAZDLBbDbj4OAAAwMDuL6+Rn19PaRSKSwWC0ZHR9k2GJgQxMyWNTc3x7aBXyU9PZ0WFhbYmNbWVna1AoAkEgmVlpaS2+0ms9lMKpUqorssvV4fccyJiQlmS05OJovFwmxWq5UKCgrCxlGr1bS9vR31u6wf2bIuLy9xdXUV1Ge1WtkB7NcZ5Pn5mbXf3t6wt7cHn88Hu93+acbz3ZhtbW1obm6GUqmEx+MJSjS0Wi12d3cxMDCAsrIyJCUlITExEYWFheju7sbh4SH0en3UdwdO+JOD8AOVAEEQQRAB38QfQtVPbkCRvTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII='

image = vision.Image(content=content)

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
texts = client.text_detection(image=image).text_annotations

for text in texts:
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))
```

Excerpt from debug log

```
I1108 20:09:43.273000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:223]      HANDSHAKE START -       TLS client start_connect  - !!!!!!
I1108 20:09:43.280000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:223]                 LOOP -    TLS client enter_early_data  - !!!!!!
I1108 20:09:43.286000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:223]                 LOOP -   TLS client read_server_hello  - !!!!!!
I1108 20:09:43.296000000 10292 src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_connect_handshaker.cc:329] Connecting to server vision.googleapis.com:443 via HTTP proxy ipv4:172.17.0.5:8080
I1108 20:09:43.476000000 10292 src/core/lib/surface/completion_queue.cc:977] grpc_completion_queue_next(cq=000001F89F023B40, deadline=gpr_timespec { tv_sec: 1636382383, tv_nsec: 676000000, clock_type: 1 }, reserved=0000000000000000)
I1108 20:09:43.521000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:223]                 LOOP - TLS client read_server_certifi  - !!!!!!
I1108 20:09:43.554000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:223]                 LOOP - TLS client read_certificate_st  - !!!!!!
I1108 20:09:43.565000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:223]                 LOOP - TLS client verify_server_certi  - !!!!!!
E1108 20:09:43.581000000 10292 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1439] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
D1108 20:09:43.594000000 10292 src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc:184] Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1636382383.594000000","description":"Handshake failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":307,"tsi_code":10,"tsi_error":"TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE"}
I1108 20:09:43.614000000 10292 src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc:1073] Connect failed: {"created":"@1636382383.594000000","description":"Handshake failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":307,"tsi_code":10,"tsi_error":"TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE"}
I1108 20:09:43.627000000 10292 src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc:1070] chand=000001F8A00D86D8: connectivity change for subchannel wrapper 000001F8A03C4C50 subchannel 000001F8A0213AD0; hopping into work_serializer
```

Comment: os.environ['https_proxy'] = http... should probably be os.environ['https_proxy'] = https:.... the http is redirected to https which triggers the ssl handshake

Comment: "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Your client is refusing to continue based on the server certificate given. Maybe because your client does not have the appropriate CAs in the trust store it uses, or there are other certificates problems like validity dates, etc.

Comment: @draz I tried with multiple combinations. http with http, https with https, https with http.  https with https throws an error as proxy uri does not support https

E1109 09:55:54.700000000  9160 src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_proxy.cc:78] 'https' scheme not supported in proxy URI

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, The same API works perfect in REST Client such as Postman. the GRPC client is failing. Seems it is not able to pickup the certificates as browsers do. Is there a way to explicitly pass the cert store details.

I have validated the certificate from postman client and it is not a expired. Again it is a public (GA) API. So no issues with the APIs. Some where the network is blocking the certs.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is usually encountered due to a number of reasons, including the following:

- **reset reason: connection failure** If you receive HTTP code 503 or gRPC
  code 14 and the message upstream connect error or disconnect/reset
  before headers. reset reason: connection failure, this indicates that
  ESPv2 can't reach the service's backend. To troubleshoot, double
  check the items below.
- **Error code 502 or 503** App Engine may take a few minutes to respond successfully to requests. If you send a request and get back
  an HTTP 502, 503, or some other server error, wait a minute and try
  the request again.
- **Networking** configurations and any proxy that can cause the handshake
  to fail.
- **Antivirus**, firewalls, or any other software that are preventing the
  traffic.
- **Corporate certificates** are being used.

You can see more possible [errors](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors).

Depending on the situation, you can check your proxy and ensure that traffic/connections to accounts.google.com are allowed for authorization. To use [corporate certificates](https://issuetracker.google.com/35907626#comment8), it is necessary to append your corporate certificate to `google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/cacerts.txt` to allow connections from Google cloud.

Another solution could be to  turn certificate verification off, by:

Set `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY environment` variable to 0. For example, run

```
export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0
python your_script
```

Or

```
PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 python your_script
```

Alternatively, you can add this to your code before doing the https request

```
import os, ssl
if (not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and
getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None)):
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

You can see more documentation [here](https://moreless.medium.com/how-to-fix-python-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-97772d9dd14c).

Comment: I tried turning off SSL but none works. Have also tried, the following, issue still persists. not sure whether it is applicable only to custom APIs hosted in google or all public apis as well.

gcloud init
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [default] are:
auth:
  disable_ssl_validation: 'True'
core:
  disable_usage_reporting: 'True'
proxy:
  address: internalproxyserver
  password: <password>
  port: '8080'
  type: http
  username: <userid>

Comment: You could see this link https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-tls-handshake-issues/.  If you have a firewall you need to check the rules.